# Problem with discriminators in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use a discriminator field in my linq to sql setup. I have a base class called `Inventory_Item` which I have setup to be abstract and then many different services that inherit from it (e.g. `BaseWash`). Now the properties for the BaseWash association are

```
Base Class Discriminator Value    = 1
Derived Class Discriminator Value = 2
Discriminator Property = ItemCategoryID
Inheritance Default = BaseWash
```

This builds fine but when it runs I get an exception in the designer code here:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Inventory_Item> Inventory_Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Inventory_Item>();
    }
}
```

> Abstract class 'ICS.Core.Inventory_Item' should not be assigned an inheritance discriminator key.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Inventory_Item` is abstract, there is no way you can ever instantiate an `Inventory_Item`. So just clear the `Base Class Discriminator Value` - it can never be used. Or make the class non-abstract and leave it at 1.

Comment: Thanks that appears to have fixed my problem. Score another point for SO.